# React Webpack - Submit Button not retrieving input value on form submit

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack with React and I can't for the life of me understand what is going on in this build. This is what's supposed to be happening.

1. The var **headerInput** changes to whatever value is inputted **onChange**.
2. When the form is submitted(**onSubmit**) the console.log logs the **headerInput** value.

**The problem**: The value that gets console logged is numerical, it's usually something like: .0.0.1. I think it's console.log'ing the click event. Why isn't the value being assigned like in the in the handlerInput function?

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks, All.

```
var headerInput = null;

import React from "react";

export default class Navigation extends React.Component{
  handlerInput(e,headerInput){
    headerInput = e.target.value;
    console.log(headerInput);
  };
  clickSubmit(e,headerInput){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(headerInput);
  };
  render(){
    return(
    <form onSubmit={this.clickSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="change header" onChange={this.handlerInput.bind(this)} />
      <button>Change Header</button>
    </form>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the recommended way to be using React. Instead of relying on a "global" to store your state, you should be using the state API that come with components.

Like so:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Navigation extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set up your default state here.
    this.state = { }; 

    // Do early binding.
    this.handlerInput = this.handlerInput.bind(this);
    this.clickSubmit = this.clickSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handlerInput(e){
    // Use setState to update the state.
    this.setState({ 
      headerInput: e.target.value
    }
  };
  clickSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // You read state via this.state
    console.log(this.state.headerInput);
  };
  render(){
    return(
    <form onSubmit={this.clickSubmit}>
      /* Make sure you pass the current state to the input */
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="change header" 
        onChange={this.handlerInput} 
        value={this.state.headerInput}
      />
      <button>Change Header</button>
    </form>
    );
  }
};
```

I definitely recommend you revisit the official react docs, like the [thinking in react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and [react forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) tutorials.

Comment: I used a global variable in this instance for testing purposes. 

I would prefer to have less states overall and just get the input value without assigning a variable at all. I learned about refs. I ended up using refs to solved the problem is this method good practice.

https://jsfiddle.net/u46Lj95r/

Answer (score 1):

If the input is strictly one-way (you only read from it) then just use a ref

```
import React from "react";

class Navigation extends React.Component{
  clickSubmit(e,headerInput){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.inputEl.value);
  };
  render(){
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.clickSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <input placeholder="change header" ref={el => this.inputEl = el} />
        <button>Change Header</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
};
```

Note that...

> Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy,
>   and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. Callback
>   refs are preferred.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html